# Feynman Diagrams with jaxodraw-2.1-0

Tags: packages, feynman

I want to use `jaxodraw` for drawing nice Feynman diagrams. I've already downloaded binaries from here http://jaxodraw.sourceforge.net/download/index.html and the program works fine.

My problem is that once I run `pdflatex` in a file with the code exported by `jaxodraw`, I only got the labels and any diagram.

This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%%JaxoComment:
%%JaxoScale{1.0}

\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
  \begin{picture}(410,314) (95,-47)
    \SetWidth{1.0}
    \SetColor{Black}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](96,194)(192,122)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](192,122)(96,50)
    \Photon(192,122)(288,122){7.5}{5}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](288,122)(384,194)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](384,50)(288,122)
    \Photon(384,194)(432,242){7.5}{3}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](504,218)(432,242)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](432,242)(504,266)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](504,146)(384,194)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](384,50)(504,98)
    \Photon(384,50)(432,2){7.5}{3}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](504,-46)(432,2)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](432,2)(504,26)
%
% There is a postscript text here!
% There is a postscript text here!
% There is a postscript text here!
\Text(139,50)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\overline{q}$}}}
\Text(233,44)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\bar{t}$}}}
  \end{picture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I read something about install the `.sty` file and I downloaded it and follow this instructions http://blog.irrepupavel.com/2007/02/installing-latex-style-files-sty-on.html, but it doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have received a number of `Non-PDF special ignored!` entries in your `.log` file after compiling this with `pdflatex`.

You need to compile your `.tex` file by following the `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` sequence, since you're dealing with [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). There are ways around compiling a document with `pstricks` functionality using `pdflatex`, but the former option is your easiest way out.

[image]

Comment: AWESOME!!!! thanks @Werner. Actually compiled it with xelatex doesn't work for me, but the other options works perfectly!!! thanks!!!!