# Jaxodraw LaTex export is not generating any figure after compilation

Tags: diagrams, feynman

I am using jaxodraw for drawing Feynman diagrams.

My problem is that once I run pdflatex in a file with the code exported by jaxodraw, I only got the labels and no diagram. I saw a similar problem was mentioned here 
[Feynman Diagrams with jaxodraw-2.1-0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33118/feynman-diagrams-with-jaxodraw-2-1-0)
but the solution mentioned there is also not working for me. I tried to compile with the steps suggested there, but of no help.

This is my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}

\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

%%JaxoComment:
%%JaxoScale{1.0}


\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
  \begin{picture}(274,98) (191,-183)
    \SetWidth{1.0}
    \SetColor{Black}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](192,-94)(272,-94)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,-94)(272,-174)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](272,-174)(192,-174)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](384,-94)(464,-94)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](384,-94)(384,-174)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2,arrowinset=0.2](464,-174)(384,-174)
    \Photon(272,-94)(384,-94){7.5}{6}
    \Photon(272,-174)(384,-174){7.5}{6}
    \Text(304,-110)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$W^-$}}}
    \Text(400,-142)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\nu_l$}}}
  \end{picture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I run `latex` (not `pdflatex`), it generates `.dvi` successfylly for me, then `dvips` produces the diagram in postscript. You can then convert it to pdf with `ps2pdf`. What kind of `TeX` environment do you use?

Comment: I'm using Texmaker. So, when I run latex and then Dvi>PS it compiles successfully, but then when I try PS>PDF, it gives me error "Process started

ps2pdf

: Invalid argument. ps2pdf: Data: 4294967295

Process exited with error(s)"

Comment: Is diagram visible in the ps file? If yes, certainly ps2pdf of your texmaker is not configured properly. If no, then some drivers might be missing

Comment: No, the diagram is not visible in the ps file. When I run 'Dvi>PS 'and then 'view PS', I got this error message "Error : could not start the command : "C:/Program Files/Ghostgum/gsview/gsview32.exe" "BanomalyBox".ps".
Probably the ps viewer driver is not correct ?! I'm not sure!

Comment: Can you use gsview32.exe on any ps file at all?

Comment: Actually there is no 'Ghostgum' folder under my program files! So, I don't know what is going on ! I can see the ps file generated by this process with my EPSViewer.

Comment: Well this again means your texmaker is not properly configured: it tries to use a ps viewer that is not there, and presumably also ps2pdf tries to use ghostscript which you do not have. Maybe installing ghostscript (optionally with gsview32) can help, but I cannot tell definitely of course whether it will help or not

Comment: Well, now I've downloaded the ghostscript and can see the diagram in ps file, but still there is problem with ps2pdf !

Comment: Sorry I don't have texmaker (I use winedt over miktex) but I used it before and vaguely remember it is somehow configurable (in the "Quick build" section) to show it where to find ghostscript