# How to compile a document that both uses jaxodraw feynman diagrams and png images

Tags: pstricks, png

I initially had a problem getting feynman diagrams, which were produced using jaxodraw, to show properly (due to using psTricks). I've solved that problem using the suggestion in the answer to question: [Feynman Diagrams with jaxodraw-2.1-0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33118/feynman-diagrams-with-jaxodraw-2-1-0)

That is, I compiled my document using latex->dvips->ps2pdf, and that solved my problem. Unfortunately when I try to include a png image in my document, I am unable to get the image to show. I get the error "cannot determine size of graphic". As a workaround, I followed the answer in question:[Cannot determine size of graphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Thus, I've included the bmpsize package and [dvipdfmx] option for the graphicx package. When I now compile using latex->dvips->ps2pd the figure shows the caption, but not the actual image. When I use pdfLatex build, the image shows up correctly, but the Feynman diagrams do not.

What type of build, or possible other solution is there, so that I can get jaxodraw feynman diagrams to show up properly, as well as png images?

This is the command I'm using for my figure.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{SomePng.png}
    \caption{Hellow World}
    \label{fig:TotalCS}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: run your document with `xelatex`

Comment: Thanks for your response, Herbert. That did not work. I guess I'm just stuck converting many png files to eps.

Comment: Would anyone recommend an image file converter that is trustworthy? I heard about Imagick and maybe Ghostscript. Suggestions?